# Can I replace Node.Js to C# but keep socket.io?

Tags: c#, node.js, server, socket.io

I have built an app which connects to node.js server and then pushes communication using socket.io to the web application and all works fine.

However I'd like to change node.js to C# but I'm not sure where to start. I watched some tutorials on ASP.NET but I don't think that this is what I need. I already have database (mySql) and a front-end (PHP). These are that I'd like to connect to the new C# server replace node.js server.

Can anyone recommend a tutorial video on youtube where I can see how to start building a server in C# and how to connect to the existing database and front-end?

If I change node.js to C#, should I change socket.io as well or I can use it? What about with PHP? is it possible to use that too or if I use C#, I should rewrite everything to be compatible with C#?

I hope it makes sense. I'm quite beginner in C# but I'd like to learn it. I know the basics to create small apps in ASP.NET but I feel that is not what I need for this project.

Comment: I think you'd have to rewrite everything so it might not be worth the trouble. You'd have to use a C# socket.io server (e.g. [this one](https://github.com/uhm0311/SocketIOSharp)). Not sure what you mean with PHP, but it sounds like you'd have to rewrite that part. Personally, I wouldn't recommend learning [C#'s ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) when you are comfortable with node.js unless you have a very specific use case where C# would really be better compared to node.js.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.